# Xamarin - Oreo (API 26) Firebase Cloud Messaging background notifications not showing in notification drawer

Tags: android, xamarin, notifications, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing an Android application using Visual Studio + Xamarin and trying to receive background Firebase Cloud Messaging notifications on Oreo (API 26).

**Problem**
When my app is backgrounded, notifications are not displayed in the notification drawer (only on Android API 26 Oreo). However notifications are working when the app is foregrounded.

**Comments**
The FCM notifications are working on all other build versions < 26, including background and foreground FCM messages (these appear in the notification drawer and I am able to launch my application from a backgrounded state, or if it's foregrounded the app opens the correct intent).

---

My settings are as follows;

### Manifest

```
Target Android Version: Android 8.0 (API level 26)
Minimum Android Version: Android 4.1 (API level 16)
```

### Android Build Tools

```
Android SDK Tools 26.1.1
Android SDK Platform-Tools 26.0.2
Android SDK Build Tools 26.0.2
```

### Firebase Cloud Messaging Payload

I'm sending the following FCM payload using the node.js firebase library:

```
var payload = {
    notification: {
        title: "My Title",
        body: "My body"
    },
    data: {
        type: 'A_CUSTOM_TYPE_VARIABLE'
    }
};
```

---

**Errors in Xamarin Application Output**
When I send an FCM from my server or via the firebase console and the app is in the background I can see that the app receives the FCM but errors before it reaches my code. There is an event output in the application output panel which reads:

```
[Notification] Use of stream types is deprecated for operations other than volume control
[Notification] See the documentation of setSound() for what to use instead with android.media.AudioAttributes to qualify your playback use case
```

**Developer Options Warning Toast**

```
Settings > System > Developer Options > Show notification channel warnings (turn on)
```

I've turned on 'Show notification channel warnings' in the developer options and I am now seeing the following error message when I broadcast and FCM message (whilst app is backgrounded):

[image: Image showing developer warning message when sending FCM]

---

**Related Stackoverflow posts**
 - [Oreo API 26 notification not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46990995/on-android-8-oreo-api-26-and-later-notification-doesnt-displayed) - Solution only talks
   about how you construct your notification. However, the
   FirebaseMessageReceiever or MainActivity does not even fire in my
   case.
 - [Notifications fail to display in Oreo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395669/notifications-fail-to-display-in-android-oreo-api-26) - Looks like there is a
   bug in the support library.

Comment: In order to get this code out the door I've ended up building against API level 25 (7.1.1) which works (FCM notifications received with foreground + background app on all API versions, including API 26 Oreo). Hope that helps anyone looking!

Comment: Did you get this working with Oreo?  I am having this exact same issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realise this is old, but for anyone else who's having issues the documentation has been updated. Judging by the screenshot, your notification channel is null. For Android 26+ you need to create one:

```
void CreateNotificationChannel()
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O)
    {
        // Notification channels are new in API 26 (and not a part of the
        // support library). There is no need to create a notification
        // channel on older versions of Android.
        return;
    }

    var channel = new NotificationChannel(MyFirebaseMessagingService.CHANNEL_ID,
                                          "FCM Notifications",
                                          NotificationImportance.Default)
                  {

                      Description = "Firebase Cloud Messages appear in this channel"
                  };

    var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.NotificationService);
    notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=vsmac#check-for-google-play-services-and-create-a-notification-channel