# startForegroundService() did not call startForeground(), but it did

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, foreground-service, remoteserviceexception

I'm having the `Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()` in my Android service, but I cannot figure out why it is happening.

My application is for media streaming, and this error only occurs when you pause from the foreground notification (turning it into a regular notification), and you then swipe the notification away, which is intended to stop my service.

Here is the only method where the `startForegroundService`, `startForeground` and `stopForeground` methods are called:

```
private void configureServiceState(long action) {
        if (action == PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY) {
            if (!mServiceInStartedState) {
                ContextCompat.startForegroundService(
                        StreamingService.this,
                        new Intent(
                                StreamingService.this,
                                StreamingService.class));
                mServiceInStartedState = true;
            } startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID,
                    buildNotification(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE));
        } else if (action == PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE) {
            stopForeground(false);

            NotificationManager mNotificationManager
                    = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            assert mNotificationManager != null;
            mNotificationManager
                    .notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,
                            buildNotification(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY));
        } else if (action == PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP) {
            mServiceInStartedState = false;
            stopForeground(true);
            stopSelf();
        }
    }
```

And here is where the delete intent of my notification is set:

```
.setDeleteIntent(
                        MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(
                                this, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP));
```

This `configureServiceState(long action)` method is called only from my `MediaSession` callbacks: `onPlay`, `onPause` and `onStop`... obviously with the action being the intended action to be performed.

The error doesn't occur when performing `onStop` from my UI, or when calling `onPause` followed by `onStop` from the UI (mirroring the action required to clear the notification), only from the notification.

All I can find about this error is that it supposedly occurs when you call `startForegroundService` but don't call `startForeground` within 5 seconds... however the `startForeground` is invoked immediately after the only time `startForegroundService` is invoked.

Additionally, an `onPlaybackStateChange` is going to my 'Now Playing' activity in the `onStop` method, which triggers that activity to run `finish()` so that the service is not being restarted that way.

What am I missing here?

Additional details:

- The service is not being partially restarted by my 'now playing' activity as code execution never reaches any of its methods.
- The code execution also never seems to re-enter `configureServiceState` before the error is produced
- If I add a breakpoint at the last possible point (`MediaButtonReceiver.handleIntent(mMediaSession, intent);` in `onStartCommand` of my service), pausing execution here and trying to debug causes the debugger to disconnect shortly after pausing
- Trying a different notification channel for the foreground vs regular notification doesn't make a difference either
- Swiping the paused notification away from the lock screen does not cause an error, it only occurs if the phone is unlocked; regardless of whether my app is actually open

Full exception:

```
android.app.RemoteServiceException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1870)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

My testing device is running Android 8.0, the project min API is 21 and target API  is 27. Device API is 26.

Comment: I've experienced this exact issue recently while creating a media service (although that's probably not entirely related). Please add your Android version and API level to your question and I'll see if I can help.

Comment: Thanks. I have added that as well as one more thing I found during debugging.

Comment: @transiti0nary if (action == PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY) is this if condition executed within 5 seconds? I mean is this conidtion `true` and ACTION_PLAY is triggered within 5 seconds?

Comment: Within 5 seconds of the service launching? I'm not sure. I could also trigger it within `onCreate` to be safe, but is there a function to check if the foreground notification is present, so I can still start it within this function when playback is moving from paused to playing (when `onCreate` won't be called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a NotificationChannel for Android O API 26 and above, otherwise you'll get the error you have experienced. See the following statement from the Android docs - [Create and Manage Notification Channels](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels):

> Starting in Android 8.0 (API level 26), all notifications must be assigned to a channel.

Here is an excerpt (take from it what you need) from a method I use for building our media notifications. You can see there is a check for Android O devices with a specific method to handle that case:

```
private fun compileNotification(context: Context, action: NotificationCompat.Action, mediaSession: MediaSessionCompat, controller: MediaControllerCompat, mMetadata: MediaMetadataCompat, art: Bitmap?, mPlaybackState: PlaybackStateCompat) {

    val description = mMetadata.description

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395669/notifications-fail-to-display-in-android-oreo-api-26
    @TargetApi(26)
    if(Utils.hasO()) {
        val channelA = mNotificationManager?.getNotificationChannel(NotificationChannelID.MEDIA_SERVICE.name)

        if(channelA == null) {
            val channelB = NotificationChannel(NotificationChannelID.MEDIA_SERVICE.name,
                    "MediaService",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
            channelB.setSound(null, null)

            mNotificationManager?.createNotificationChannel(channelB)
        }
    }

    val notificationBuilder = if(Utils.hasLollipop()) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NotificationChannelID.MEDIA_SERVICE.name)
    } else {
        NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    }

    notificationBuilder
            .setStyle(android.support.v4.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                    // Show actions 0,2,4 in compact view
                    .setShowActionsInCompactView(0,2,4)
                    .setMediaSession(mediaSession.sessionToken))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_icon)
            .setShowWhen(false)
            .setContentIntent(controller.sessionActivity)
            .setContentTitle(description.title)
            .setContentText(description.description)
            .setLargeIcon(art)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setOngoing(mPlaybackState.state == PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)

            if(!Utils.hasLollipop()) {
                notificationBuilder
                        .setStyle(android.support.v4.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                                // Show actions 0,2,4 in compact view
                                .setShowActionsInCompactView(0,2,4)
                                .setMediaSession(mediaSession.sessionToken)
                                .setShowCancelButton(true)
                                .setCancelButtonIntent(MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(context,
                                        PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP)))
                        // Stop the service when the notification is swiped away
                        .setDeleteIntent(MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(context,
                                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP))
            }

    notificationBuilder.addAction(NotificationCompat.Action(
            R.drawable.exo_controls_previous,
            "Previous",
            MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(context,
                    PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS)))
    notificationBuilder.addAction(NotificationCompat.Action(
            R.drawable.ic_replay_10_white_24dp,
            "Rewind",
            MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(context,
                    PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_REWIND)))

    notificationBuilder.addAction(action)

    notificationBuilder.addAction(NotificationCompat.Action(
            R.drawable.ic_forward_10_white_24dp,
            "Fast Foward",
            MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(context,
                    PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_FAST_FORWARD)))
    notificationBuilder.addAction(NotificationCompat.Action(
            R.drawable.exo_controls_next,
            "Next",
            MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(context,
                    PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT)))

    (context as MediaService).startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build())
}
```

In your `onStop()` callback, you'll need to call `stopSelf()` within the service. Then, when your service `onDestroy()` method is called you need to clean up a few things (as applies to your case) as follows:

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()

    abandonAudioFocus()
    unregisterReceiver(mNoisyReceiver)

    //Deactivate session
    mSession.isActive = false
    mSession.release()

    NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).cancelAll()

    if(mWiFiLock?.isHeld == true) mWiFiLock?.release()

    stopForeground(true)
}
```

I haven't included detail for some of the methods above, but the method names should be self commenting - let me know if I can include more detail. Some of them might be overkill, but in your case might solve the issue.

I'm pretty sure this will solve your issue. If it doesn't I have a few more ideas.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot later today if I can. One thing though, my notification building function does run this notification channel function shown here: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels is that doing the same thing? 

Another thing I notice is that my builder does not have an additional `setStyle` if `!Utils.hasLollipop()`, and always uses this constructor  `NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL)`, regardless of `hasLollipop`. Could it be related to that?

Comment: In that case it might be a different issue - I still think it might be worth trying the above if it's not too much hassle. Usually the compat libraries do in fact handle the different Android version checks.

Comment: @transiti0nary I've added some more details about how I handle the `onStop()` method in my media service. Please let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: There could be an issue in your code calling `stopForeground(true);` before `stopSelf();` - stopSelf() doesn't kill the service immediately.

Comment: If this or any answer has solved your question or helped in any way please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 5):

Just wasted way too many hours on this. I'm not sure that this is what you are experiencing, but in my case I kept getting this exception because my `NOTIFICATION_ID` was `0` ... Using any other value seems to fix this.-_-

Comment: Even though it's not the case here, I experienced this too! Took a long time to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue. The problem was using `PendingIntent.getForegroundService()` on notification items click to update media service. Using just `PendingIntent.getService` solved the issue for me.

Comment: Interesting, but I don't think I am using that method directly. The notification interactions send MediaButton events which are received by my service and handled

Comment: I have same issue with Android 8, 9 and replace PendingIntent.getForegroundService() with PendingIntent.getService solve it