# C2D_MESSAGE permission changed for API 23?

Tags: android, android-permissions

This question is similar to

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/157912/did-the-meaning-of-protection-level-signature-change-with-android-6

but I really didn't get the answer from that post.  I also saw some posts on C2D_MESSAGE, but never saw anything about the permission no longer working in 23+.

In my manifest, so that I can build and receive GCM notifications, I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.mydomain.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<permission android:name="com.mydomain.myapp.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Now I have to target API level 26, so I had to go to the new permission level.  My phone is no longer getting the notifications I build.  Do I need to specifically request the C2D_MESSAGE permission now, and if so, how do I do that?  --- Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395669/notifications-fail-to-display-in-android-oreo-api-26

Answer (score 0):

Yes -- it was the post I just referenced.  This has nothing to do with permissions.  For API 26 and above, you have to configure a NotificationChannel.  And make sure to compile for 8.0, or it won't know what a NotificationChannel is.